# Recover directory deleted from C#

Tags: windows, file-recovery

I used the following C# code to delete a directory:

```
Directory.Delete ("C:\TC");
```

Can I restore the directory `C:\TC`? Can I also restore the subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva): a piece of software from the same people who make [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) and [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

---

Either that or you could create a duplicate of the directory in a temporary folder, and then *only* delete the temp directory after the user is 100% sure that's what they want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think if you delete the files using the proper ShellOperation API call you can then find those files in the bin of Windows, with your code above I guess they are gone forever.

On the other hand if you use any of those third party tools usually called Undelete, you should be able to restore most of them I guess.

Comment: Whether an undelete tool will help depends a lot on how long ago the deletion was.  Undelete tools can only work with data that hasn't been overwritten yet, and the longer it's been, the greater the chance that the deleted file's clusters have been reused.