# How can I recover files deleted in java?

Tags: java, windows

I did a mistake and deleted `.wav` files using `File.delete()` in Java.

I use Windows 7 and NetBeans IDE 7.0. How can I restore the files?

Comment: From backup....

Comment: Use a [file recovery tool](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm). And, as @MarcinOrlowski already said, always keep a backup of important data, so that you have it if you need to restore it

Comment: This issue is off-topic since it is not about programming. You are actually asking for some backup / recovery tool...

Comment: You may find this useful; not java, but C# so principal the same. Regardless, I think the answer is the same. http://superuser.com/questions/297446/recover-deleted-files-c Use Recuva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a recovery tools to recover my files and it works fine 
[recovery tools](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm)

Answer (score 3):

If you're lucky, you can recover your files from the *Local History* in your IDE. Right click on your project and check it.

Comment: Thank you, but by this way I can recover deleted source files not files that I had deleted from my code

Answer (score -1):

Delete file recovery in netbean and eclipes is too easy. Follow this steps
A. Right click on the folder. B.Choose Local History – Restore Deleted. C.Done